# Error while converting PIL image to Tkinter image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, photoimage

I'm trying to rotate an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCOm8.jpg) using Pillow:

```py
img = Image.open("./assets/aircraftCarrier/aircraftCarrier0.gif")

img = img.rotate(270)
```

This rotates the image but when I try to save it Pillow doesn't seem to recognise the file type, even if I put the format type when saving it:

```py
img.save("./tempData/img", "GIF")
```

It comes up with a [file with a blank extension](https://send.firefox.com/download/af45d31b7421b420/#sAKo0Vw5HQ5sdABB9Y4WUg)

Now this doesn't really matter as long as tkinter can recognise it with PhotoImage, but that doesn't seem to work either:

```py
img = PhotoImage(img)

label = Label(root, image=img)
label.pack()
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Image)
```

I'm not really sure what I've done wrong or if I need to do more processing with Pillow.

Help would be greatly appreciated,

Josh

---

**Full code:**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from PIL import Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")


img = Image.open("./assets/aircraftCarrier/aircraftCarrier0.gif")

img = img.rotate(270)

img.save("./tempData/img", "GIF")

img = PhotoImage(img)

label = Label(root, image=img)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Full error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshlucpoll\Documents\Battleships\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    label = Label(root, image=img)
  File "C:\Users\Joshlucpoll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Joshlucpoll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Image)
```

Comment: You are trying to rotate a GIF, not a png or jpg. Have tried png or jpg to see if the error occurs with GIF only?

Comment: @BlackThunder Tried for both jpg and png but the result is the exact same

Comment: This looks incorrect: `img = PhotoImage(img)`. Tkinter's `PhotoImage` class doesn't take an image as its first parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looking into the [effbot documentation](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) for `PhotoImage` there are these lines of code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("lenna.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

and it states:

> If you need to work with other file formats, the Python Imaging
>   Library (PIL) contains classes that lets you load images in over 30
>   formats, and convert them to Tkinter-compatible image objects

So it seems you need to add `ImageTk` before `PhotoImage` when converting from PIL to Tkinter.

Eg:

`img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)`

Adding this to my program does result in the rotated image to show perfectly.